# Calling Recursive Function with Async Callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

**Context:** I'm preparing for some job interviews and brushing up on some of the computer science basics. I was implementing several algorithms for traversing binary sort trees, in particular in-order traversal, and I was able to do it just fine with synchronous functions as well as promises and the async/await keywords.

For an added set of practice, I thought porting it over to asynchronous callback functions would be a useful challenge, especially since I'm interviewing for Node.js positions. But I'm absolutely stuck on it, and while I'm better off moving on and studying other topics, this defeat has been bothering me and I keep spinning my wheels!

So consider this a fun yet challenging twist on a classic algorithm problem, not for the faint of heart!

**Data** So imagine you're given an array of objects, each one representing a node. A node must have a `value` and optionally `left` and `right` attributes that correspond to the index number of another node in the array. So something like this:

```
[
   {"value":"root","left":1,"right":2},
   {"value":"L1","right":3},
   {"value":"R1"},
   {"value":"R2"}
]
```

If you draw this out as a binary tree, it looks like:

```
     root
     /   \
    /     \
   L1      R1
    \
     \
     R2
```

And implement in order traversal, the values should appear as `L1, R2, root, R1'.

In the synchronous solution, I have written up a couple of helper methods to to get the root node (assuming the first element of the array is always the root) and another method to find the node at a specific index. And the solution is as follows:

```
function SyncTree(data) {
    this.data = data;
};

SyncTree.prototype.getRoot = function () {
    return this.data[0];
};

SyncTree.prototype.getNode = function (index) {
    return this.data[index];
};

SyncTree.prototype.orderTree = function () {
  const results = [];

  const inorder = node => {
    if (node) {
      inorder(this.getNode(node.left));
      results.push(node.value);
      inorder(this.getNode(node.right));
    }
  }

  inorder(this.getRoot());
  return results;
}
```

And for the promise based solution, I made my helper functions return a promise object instead of just the value, and I was able to handle that pretty easily because async/await makes code look synchronous anyway.

```
function PromiseTree(data) {
    if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
        throw new Error('The data must be an Array');
    }
    this.data = data;
};

PromiseTree.prototype.getRoot = function (callback) {
   return Promise.resolve(this.data[0]);
};

PromiseTree.prototype.getNode = function (index, callback) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.data[index]);
};

PromiseTree.prototype.orderTree = function () {
  const results = [];

  const inorder = async node => {
    if (node) {
      const left = await this.getNode(node.left);
      await inorder(left);
      results.push(node.value);
      const right = await this.getNode(node.right);
      await inorder(right);
    }
  }

  return this.getRoot().then(async root => {
    await inorder(root);
    return Promise.resolve(results);
  });
}
```

For the callback challenge, I wrote some simple logic that would make it return a value immediately or delayed at random. I know in the real world, using callback functions for this use case would be absolutely retarded and the synchronous method would be preferred, but I'm banging my head on the wall and I'm stuck. So far, this is what I've got, but it returns inconsistent results because certain callback functions are firing off before others.

```
function CallbackTree(data) {
    if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
        throw new Error('The data must be an Array');
    }
    this.data = data;
};

function inconsistentCallback(value, callback) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        setImmediate(function () {
            callback(null, value);
        });
    } else {
        callback(null, value);
    }

}

CallbackTree.prototype.getRoot = function (callback) {
    inconsistentCallback(this.data[0], callback);
};

CallbackTree.prototype.getNode = function (index, callback) {
    inconsistentCallback(this.data[index], callback);
};

CallbackTree.prototype.orderTree = function (callback) {
  const results = [];

  const inorder = (node, cb) => {
    if (node) {
      results.push(node.value)
      this.getNode(node.left, (err, left) => {
        this.getNode(node.right, (err, right) => {
          inorder(node.left, cb)
          inorder(node.right, cb)
          cb()
        })
      })
    }
  }

  this.getRoot((err, root) => {
    inorder(root, () => {
      if (results.length === this.data.length) {
        callback(null, results)
      }
    });
  });

}
```